# How can I render .ejs file from node.js controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I have the following folder structure:

bin

controllers

models

node_modules

public

routes

views

app.js

package.json

As I am new to node.js and express.js, I would like to know how to render .ejs file from the controller file. Currently, my code looks like:

//controllers/login.js

```
module.exports = {
    getLoginPage: function (req, res) {
        res.render('login-form');
    }
};
```

//routes/login.js

```
var login = require('../controllers/login');
module.exports = function(app){    
    app.get('/', login.getLoginPage);
};
```

//app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //parses information from POST
var stylus = require('stylus');
var validator = require('express-validator');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

require('./routes/login')(app);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(stylus.middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({secret: 'max', saveUninitialized: false, resave: false}));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

In my controller, if I write res.send("Hello");, it prints but I want the entire .ejs file to show up on my browser. How is this possible?

Also, if I render the .ejs from my routes, it's displaying properly but not from the controllers.

//error

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\node\folder-name\views"
    at EventEmitter.render (C:\node\folder-name\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\node\folder-name\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
    at C:\node\folder-name\app.js:60:7
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\node\folder-name\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\node\folder-name\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\node\folder-name\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\node\folder-name\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\node\folder-name\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\node\folder-name\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (C:\node\folder-name\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
```

Thanks

Comment: @DevAymen The solution doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Change your view path to this:-

```
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname+'/views/'));
```

then in controller you can simply use

```
//assuming hello.ejs is in your view folder
response.render('hello.ejs');
```

and if you have folders in views folder then use

```
response.render('error/404.ejs');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set the rendering engine for views:

```
app.set('view engine','ejs');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the view engine to ejs :

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

[Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Comment: can you show more code and info, like is the view directly in the views folder or in a sub folder. what is the error message ?

Comment: please check the updated question. and yes, .ejs files are under views folder.

Comment: from what i see. the app reaches the error handler you set in the app.js and when it reached `res.render('error')` it couldn't find the error view. which is weird cause the `app.use` is after the route handler and logically the middleware was not supposed to be reached as you are not calling `next()` in your routes.... try removing both the 404 forward to error handler and the error handler, and see if the view is rendered

Comment: after removing those codes, its giving me this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined".

Comment: Where is that error occuring. i assume the error message is pointing to the line of the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var path = require('path');
res.render(path.resolve('./views/error'))
```